# Check for Revoked Access and Password Change in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the Facebook SDK to connect my native Android app to Facebook. I am able to show the login page and make users login into my application through their facebook account. But according to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso

I have to watch out for two activities, such as revoke of access and password change. The response parameter will return the following results:

`User revoked access to your app:
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: User 1053947411 has not authorized application 157111564357680."}}`

`OR when password changed:
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out."}}`

Now, my question is, how do I handle or catch the following errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an official guide for that: [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/).

For android it states:

> **Android native applications**
>
> You may detect access token errors by inspecting the response
>   parameter of the onComplete method. In this case, you will again need
>   to call facebook.authorize() to re-authenticate the user and generate
>   a fresh access token.